# Photo library equivalency

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there an equivalent for this uiimagepickercontroller method that, if the app is being tested in the iOS simulator, uses a generic photo from the photo library? I'd like to use AVFoundation/AVCam.

```
-(void)takePhoto {
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
imagePickerController.sourceType =     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
#else
imagePickerController.sourceType =     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
#endif
imagePickerController.editing = YES;
imagePickerController.delegate = (id)self;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

Method 2

```
 - (void)snapStillImage //this is being called on did load
{

dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
// Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.
[[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];
// Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
[ViewController5 setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];
// Capture a still image.
[[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
    {
        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

        photo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[photo.image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[photo.image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
        [self uploadPhoto];
}
}];
});
}
```

Comment: The simulator has no camera.

Comment: The pragma mark brings up the photo library instead of the picture taking interface when being tested in the simulator . I need this for the avcamera code.

Comment: I know how conditional compilation works. I'm talking about `snapStillImage`. You can't do that on the simulator. It has no camera.